# Need some help with random related products code

Tags: product-attribute, product-relations

I've been playing with some code that will display random products from the same category in the related products block.

The code works, however I would only like to display products that contain images. There are two ways I can do this, by either specifying a filter for images or I have an attribute that has a 0 or 1 value. 1 meaning it contains an image.

Here is the entire code:

```
{
public function getRelatedProducts($limit = false) {
    $products = $this->getData('related_products');
    if (!$products) {
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

        if ($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {

        } elseif ($product) {
            $ids = $product->getCategoryIds();

            if (!empty($ids)) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($ids[0]);
            }
        }

        if ($category) {
            if ($limit === false) {
                $limit = Mage::getStoreConfig('autorelated/general/limit');
            }


            $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
                    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG

                ))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setPageSize($limit);

            if ($product) {
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                    'neq' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())
                );
            }

            $products->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
            Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
            $this->setData('related_products', $products);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $products;
}
}
```

Now, here is the section I've been focusing on:

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
                    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG

                ))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setPageSize($limit);

            if ($product) {
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                    'neq' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())
                );
            }
```

I've tried the following

```
->addAttributeToFilter('image_updated',array('eq' => 1))
```

and

```
->addAttributeToFilter('image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))
```

directly bellow:

```
*->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)*
```

But products without images are still appearing in the random related products.

I believe it may be because the loaded resource model doesn't contain the attributes I'm looking to filter.

Can someone see what I am missing to use either piece of code to filter out products that do not contain images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mage_Reports` product collection is not the right collection to use here. Its definition points to some manual joins and attribute selection which I suspect (and you surmise) is interfering with your image logic.

Switch to `catalog/product_collection` and see what happens.